# Error message when trying to compile Assembly function

Tags: assembly, arm

So I am trying to work with a c driver and arm assembly function that takes array of ints and checks that all are positive and works with the driver.

driver

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 extern int absarray( int array[], int size ) ;

 int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
int array[] = {1, 3, -5, -252, 280, -332 } ;
int asize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) ;
int result ;
int i ;

result = absarray( array, asize ) ;
for( i = 0 ; i < asize ; i++ )
    printf( " %d  ", array[i] ) ;
printf( "\n" ) ;
exit( 0 ) ;

}
```

and the function

```
AREA    Program, CODE, READONLY
ENTRY

Main

   EOR R3,R3,R3; Clear R3

   ADD R3,R1,R3; load R3 with R1 ie address

   EOR R0,R0,R0; clear R0

   ADD R0,R1,R0; load R0 with the size

   EOR R4,R4,R4; clear R4

Loop

   LDR R5,[R3] ; load R5 with the value at address

   ADD R4,R4,R5 ; add R4 with the value present at address,signed

   ADD R3,R3,#4; increment address pointer by 4 as int is 4 bytes

   SUB R0,R0,#1; decrease the count

   CMP R0,#0; compare the count with 0 to check for end of array

   BNE Loop ;loop back if count is not 0

   MOV PC,R14 ; load Pc with the return address with the result stored in R4

END
```

when I try to compile

```
 arm-non-eabi-gcc -o test -c -g test1.s
```

I get a bunch of bad instructions for the whole code

when I change it to .asm

```
 arm-non-eabi.gcc -o test -c -g test1.asm
```

I get the error saying linker input file unused because linking not done

how to do I get these two to work with each other and display the output given in the c driver?

Comment: Your assembly is not compatible with gcc/gas, this looks a lot like the syntax used by Keil. Also, to be honest, this code is very inefficient and could be done a LOT better. It is also broken in multiple ways (if that code is supposed to be your absarray function).

Comment: That's an... _interesting_ implementation of `mov r3, r1`. Are both parameters really in `r1`? (hint: no) As for the label and directive syntax, [start here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html).